# URLCredentialStorage - Error adding cred. Error=-25299

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store URLCredential (builded from .p12 certificate selected in iCloud storage) permanently using URLCredentialStorage.  URLCredential seem to be fine (it has identityRef and one certificate).

```
let credential = URLCredential(
        identity: ident.identityRef,
        certificates: ident.certArray as [AnyObject],
        persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.permanent)

URLCredentialStorage.shared.set(credential, for: protectionSpace)
```

The problem is that after execution of the code above i get this error printed in the console:

```
CredStore - setIdentityCred - Error adding cred.  Error=-25299, attrs={
   labl = "http://website.com:80/";
   "v_Ref" = "<SecIdentityRef: 0x1c4437820>";
}
```

After that Im able to retrieve stored credentials later, but its not working properly (server does not accept it). The problem seems to exist only on iOS 11+. On iOS 10 storing, retrieving and using the same credentials and the same code works absolutely fine. I did not find any changes in iOS 11 changelog which could be relevant to this problem.

Can anynone please suggest solution or possible problems that could cause this behaviour?